# How can I fit a dataset with linear function and then with a cosine function?

Tags: python, data-analysis, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize, data-fitting

I need to fit with Python the following dataset in such a way that for x from -0.65 to -0.049 the fitting is linear and from 0.049 to 1.85 a cosine with a period around 0.400;

```
x = [ 1.85      ,  1.74990234,  1.65004883,  1.54995117,  1.45009766,
            1.35      ,  1.24990234,  1.15004883,  1.04995117,  0.95009766,
            0.85      ,  0.74990234,  0.65004883,  0.54995117,  0.45009766,
            0.35      ,  0.24990234,  0.15004883,  0.04995117, -0.04990234,
           -0.15      , -0.25009766, -0.34995117, -0.45004883, -0.54990234,
           -0.65      ]
y = [-1.9764485 , -2.51604791, -2.47880877, -1.65158466, -0.57161459,
       -1.73628227, -1.67898043, -2.63570217, -0.51512979, -0.73739313,
       -1.37574256, -1.96644884, -0.57822485, -0.57741358, -1.14066144,
       -1.64367465, -1.4994257 , -0.11035846, -0.36308983,  0.81232546,
       -1.22662672, -0.36636166, -0.91063433,  0.52619598, -0.53499829,
        0.19404025]
```

I used the following function to fit the data for x>0 and the results are in the attached plot. However, with this function I cannot fit linearly for x<0 . Before x = 0 it has to be linear because of physical constrains. [image]

```
def fcos(x, a, w1, ph, off):
    return a*np.cos((2*np.pi/w1)*(x - ph)) + off
ind = []; val = []
for index, item in enumerate(x):
    if item > 0.5:
        ind.append(index)
        val.append(item )
i_fit = y[i][ind[0]:ind[-1]])
guess = [0.7, 0.5, 0.1, -2]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(fcos, x[ind[0]:ind[-1]], i_fit[i], guess)
```

Comment: What are the constraints for the connection of the two curves?

Comment: I must say that your data doesn't suggest any difference between negative and positive parts, the pattern looks pretty similar and very non-linear. Either your errors are so high that any function will fit, or your measurements were incorrect - in either case, you'll unlikely get anything meaningful from your analysis.

Comment: Why should we expect that the first half is linear? Given your data, that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, I don't see why there should be a discontinuity between the first and second halves of the domain. Do a three-stage fit - FFT, clipped FFT and `curve_fit` with a linear term and it behaves well enough (given how much noise there is and how low the resolution is).

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def load_data() -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    x = ( 1.85      ,  1.74990234,  1.65004883,  1.54995117,  1.45009766,
          1.35      ,  1.24990234,  1.15004883,  1.04995117,  0.95009766,
          0.85      ,  0.74990234,  0.65004883,  0.54995117,  0.45009766,
          0.35      ,  0.24990234,  0.15004883,  0.04995117, -0.04990234,
         -0.15      , -0.25009766, -0.34995117, -0.45004883, -0.54990234,
         -0.65      )
    y = (-1.9764485 , -2.51604791, -2.47880877, -1.65158466, -0.57161459,
         -1.73628227, -1.67898043, -2.63570217, -0.51512979, -0.73739313,
         -1.37574256, -1.96644884, -0.57822485, -0.57741358, -1.14066144,
         -1.64367465, -1.4994257 , -0.11035846, -0.36308983,  0.81232546,
         -1.22662672, -0.36636166, -0.91063433,  0.52619598, -0.53499829,
          0.19404025)

    return np.array(x[::-1]), np.array(y[::-1])


def get_approx_fft(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> tuple[
    np.ndarray,  # frequency axis
    np.ndarray,  # complex spectrum
    float,       # sampling period
]:
    # assume that x is uniform; this is nearly true
    tsample = np.diff(x).mean()  # almost exactly 0.1
    f = np.fft.rfftfreq(n=x.size, d=tsample)
    spectrum = np.fft.rfft(y, norm='forward')
    return f, spectrum, tsample


def peak_near_target(spectrum: np.ndarray, n: int, tsample: float) -> int:
    target_period = 0.4
    target_index = n * tsample / target_period
    target_lower = int(np.floor(target_index)) - 1
    target_upper = int(np.ceil(target_index)) + 1
    peak_index = np.abs(
        spectrum[target_lower: target_upper + 1]
    ).argmax() + target_lower
    return peak_index


def interpolate_peak(spectrum: np.ndarray, n: int, tsample: float) -> int:
    peak_index = peak_near_target(spectrum, n, tsample)

    # http://www.ericjacobsen.org/fe2/fe2.htm
    a, b, c = spectrum[peak_index - 1: peak_index + 2]
    delta = np.real((a - c)/(2*b - a - c))

    fres = 1/n/tsample
    f1 = peak_index*fres
    f_peak = f1 + delta*fres
    excerpt_size = int(np.round(n * f1/f_peak))
    return excerpt_size


def cos_params(spectrum: np.ndarray, n: int, tsample: float, t0: float) -> tuple[float, float, float, float]:
    dc = np.real(spectrum[0])
    idx = peak_near_target(spectrum, n, tsample)
    peak = spectrum[idx]
    a_cos = 2*np.abs(peak)
    f_cos = idx / n / tsample
    p0 = t0/f_cos * 2*np.pi
    p_cos = (np.angle(peak) + p0) % (2*np.pi)
    return dc, a_cos, f_cos, p_cos


def make_t_hires(t: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return np.linspace(t.min(), t.max(), 201)


def cos_reconstruct(
    t: np.ndarray, dc: float, a_cos: float, f_cos: float, p_cos: float,
) -> np.ndarray:
    return dc + a_cos*np.cos(2*np.pi*f_cos*t + p_cos)


def get_clipped_fft(y: np.ndarray, tsample: float, excerpt_size: int) -> tuple[
    np.ndarray,  # frequency axis
    np.ndarray,  # complex spectrum
]:
    y = y[-excerpt_size:]
    f = np.fft.rfftfreq(n=y.size, d=tsample)
    spectrum = np.fft.rfft(y, norm='forward')
    return f, spectrum


def plot(
    x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray,
    t_hires: np.ndarray, y_cos: np.ndarray,
    f_approx: np.ndarray, spectrum_approx: np.ndarray,
    f: np.ndarray, spectrum: np.ndarray,
    popt: np.ndarray,
) -> plt.Figure:
    y_recon_lores = reconstruct_all(x, *popt)
    y_recon_hires = reconstruct_all(t_hires, *popt)
    spectrum_recon = np.fft.rfft(y_recon_lores, norm='forward')

    ax_t: plt.Axes
    ax_f: plt.Axes
    fig, (ax_t, ax_f) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)

    ax_t.plot(x, y, label='experiment')
    ax_t.plot(t_hires, y_cos, label='FFT fit')
    ax_t.plot(t_hires, y_recon_hires, label='curve fit')
    ax_t.set_xlabel('time')
    ax_t.set_ylabel('amplitude')
    ax_t.legend()

    ax_f.plot(f_approx, np.abs(spectrum_approx), label='complete FFT')
    ax_f.plot(f, np.abs(spectrum), label='clipped FFT')
    ax_f.plot(f_approx, np.abs(spectrum_recon), label='output FFT')
    ax_f.set_xlabel('frequency')
    ax_f.set_ylabel('amplitude')
    ax_f.legend()

    return fig


def reconstruct_all(
    x: np.ndarray,
    a_cos: float, f_cos: float, p_cos: float, dc: float, m: float,
) -> np.ndarray:
    return cos_reconstruct(x, dc, a_cos, f_cos, p_cos) + m*x


def fit(
    x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray,
    dc_est: float, a_cos: float, f_cos: float, p_cos: float,
) -> np.ndarray:
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(
        f=reconstruct_all,
        xdata=x, ydata=y,
        p0=(a_cos, f_cos, p_cos, dc_est, -1),
    )
    return popt


def main() -> None:
    x, y = load_data()
    f_approx, spectrum_approx, tsample = get_approx_fft(x, y)
    excerpt_size = interpolate_peak(spectrum_approx, n=x.size, tsample=tsample)

    f, spectrum = get_clipped_fft(y, tsample, excerpt_size)
    dc_est, a_cos, f_cos, p_cos = cos_params(spectrum, n=excerpt_size, tsample=tsample, t0=x[0])
    t = make_t_hires(x)
    y_cos = cos_reconstruct(t, dc_est, a_cos, f_cos, p_cos)

    popt = fit(x, y, dc_est, a_cos, f_cos, p_cos)

    plot(x, y, t, y_cos, f_approx, spectrum_approx, f, spectrum, popt)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: fits]

Comment: Thanks for your analysis! I was asking for a linear fit before x=0, because before that time the measurements of the sample should be around zero... and then Y values should be go down very fast + oscillations.. this comes from the sample properties..

Comment: @Krystal Your data do not show a proximity to zero before x=0. If you have different data that do, please show them.